# Add administration sw-media-quickinfo action in Shopware 6

Tags: vue.js, shopware6

how to add administration action here [image: action]?

I know that I have to override or extend component but how to find correct one and what to put in second override argument?
`Shopware.Component.override('sw-media-?', );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component you're looking for is `sw-media-quickinfo` and the second argument of the override function is the configuration that should override the original configuration of the component. You can provide you own template with that new configuration. Within the template you can use the twig `parent` function to append/prepend blocks.

```js
import template from './sw-media-quickinfo.html.twig';

const { Component } = Shopware;

Component.override('sw-media-quickinfo', {
    template,

    methods: {
        onClickMyCustomAction() {
            const currentlySelected = this.item;
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

`sw-media-quickinfo.html.twig`:

```html
{# append the last action in the sidebar #}
{% block sw_media_quickinfo_quickactions_delete %}
    {% parent %}

    <li @click="onClickMyCustomAction">
        <sw-icon
            small
            name="regular-moon"
            class="sw-media-sidebar__quickactions-icon"
        />
        {{ $tc('swag-example.sidebar.actions.myCustomAction') }}
    </li>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why `{% parent %}` instead of twig's`{{ parent() }}`?

Comment: It's a different implementation of `twig`. See [twig.js](https://github.com/twigjs/twig.js).

Comment: Ok, this works. Thank you. One last question. Why we are not using Component.extend() here?

Comment: Because extending would create an entirely new component that inherits the configuration of another component, as opposed to overriding the configuration of an existing component.